# Access content inside a controller function ember

Tags: ember.js

I have a route, controller, view like this. The problem is I called controller function `reloadTime` from view but in `reloadTime` function I console the content for this controller but it says it is `undefined`. My question is how to access this content in ember?

```
App.ActivecallsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    setupController:function(controller,model){
        $.ajax({
            url:'requests/activecalls.php',
            type:'POST',
            success:function(data){
                App.Cdrglobal.set('active_call',data.length);
                controller.set('content',data);
            }
        })
    }
});

App.ActivecallsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    content:[],
    deleteCall:function(model){
       var obj = this.findProperty('ID',model.ID);
       App.Cdrglobal.set('active_call',App.Cdrglobal.active_call-1);
       this.removeObject(obj);
    },
    reloadTime:function(){
        console.log(this.get('content'));//console undefined
        console.log(this.content);console undefined
    }
});


App.ActivecallsView = Ember.View.extend({
   didInsertElement:function(){
       this.get('controller').reloadTime();
   }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are accessing the `content` property correctly.  The reason why you are getting `undefined` is because the `content` property is actually undefined.

Now the reason why your `content` is undefined, is because Ember.js automatically sets the controller's content to the return value of the `model` hook in the route.

Since you didn't define a `model` method, the return value if this hook is `undefined` and therefore Ember.js is setting the controller `content` property to `undefined`.

Solution:

Create a dummy model hook that just returns an empty array:

```
App.ActivecallsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  setupController:function(controller,model){
    $.ajax({
      url:'requests/activecalls.php',
      type:'POST',
      success:function(data){
        App.Cdrglobal.set('active_call',data.length);
        controller.set('content',data);
      }
    });
  },
  model: function() {
    return [];
  }
});
```