# Ember controller non-restful action and variable scope

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I've been banging my head on this for a while now. I'm trying to make a simple PUT ajax call from my Ember controller to /tasks/:id/complete. Here's what I have currently:

```
var TasksShowController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({       
  actions: {                                                    
    complete: function(){    
      var model = this.get('content');            
      var adapter = this.container.lookup('adapter:application');
      adapter.ajax(this.completeTaskUrl(adapter), 'PUT')     
        .then(function(response) {                              
          //model undefined, scope is window                    
          debugger;                                             
          model.setProperties(response.task);                   
        }, this.completeFailure);                               
    }                                                           
  }
```

I'm trying to use the configuration from the adapter instead of a vanilla `Ember.$.ajax` because I need to pass along the headers and domain that are already configured in the RESTAdapter. Any thoughts? Am I just missing something thats making this harder than it should be?

```
DEBUG: Ember      : 1.5.0 
DEBUG: Ember Data : 1.0.0-beta.7+canary.b45e23ba
DEBUG: Handlebars : 1.3.0 
DEBUG: Handlebars : 1.3.0
```

Comment: Are you sure it's the model that is undefined? See

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15893833/access-content-inside-a-controller-function-ember