# setting data from route to controller error in Emberjs

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, ember.js, frontend

i am a newbie in Emberjs.. 
I am trying to set data content from Emberjs route to controller to display in template..

i followed the suggestions here..
[Access content inside a controller function ember](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15893833/access-content-inside-a-controller-function-ember)

works perfect.. but now i am getting this error

```
Uncaught Error: Assertion Failed: The value that #each loops over must be an Array. You passed {items: [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object], title: current mood}
```

edit:
here is also my code..

http://screencast.com/t/4fXm5n5u9lpH

and here is my template code

http://screencast.com/t/horNlooKx8l

any feedback would be appreciated

thanks

Comment: you need to post your code, we can't guess what your are doing :(

Comment: ive edited my post to a screenshot of my code.. ehe thanks :-) @fanta

Comment: ive added code for my template.. thanks @fanta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that https://torid-heat-7210.firebaseio.com/fixed_column.json returns an Object (`{}`) where as `{{#each}}` helper is expecting an array (`[]`).

You can modify your `setupController` method as follows to get it to work:

```
setupController: function(controller){
  Ember.$.ajax({
    url: 'https://torid-heat-7210.firebaseio.com/fixed_column.json',
    type: 'GET'
  }).done(function(data){
    controller.set('content', data.items);
  })
}
```

Working solution [here](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/baqivo/1/edit?html,js,console,output)